# How can I check if a program is running in the background using a cron, and start it if needed?

Tags: php, cron, background-process, daemon, akeneo

I have the task to run a daemon in the background on a production server. However, I do want to be sure that this daemon always runs. The daemon is PHP process.

I tried to approach this by checking if the daemon is running, and if not: start it. So I have a command like:

```
if [ $(ps ax | grep -c "akeneo:batch:job-queue-consumer-daemon") -lt 3 ]; then php /home/sibo/www/bin/console akeneo:batch:job-queue-consumer-daemon & fi
```

I first do an `if` with `ps` and `grep -c` to check if there are processes running with a given name, and if not: I start the command ending with an `&`, forcing it to start.

The above command works, if I execute it from the command line the process gets started and I can see that is is running when I execute a simple `ps ax`-command.

However, as soon as I try to do this using the crontab it doesn't get started:

```
* * * * * if [ $(ps ax | grep -c "akeneo:batch:job-queue-consumer-daemon") -lt 3 ]; then php /home/sibo/www/bin/console akeneo:batch:job-queue-consumer-daemon & fi
```

I also set the `MAILTO`-header in the crontab, but I'm not getting any e-mails as well.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my approach? And how I can get it started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy and old-style one is to create a bash file where you basically check if the process is running, otherwise you start it.

Here the content of the bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(ps -efa | grep -v grep | grep job-queue-consumer-daemon -c) -gt 0 ] ;
then
    echo "Process running ...";
else
    php /home/sibo/www/bin/console akeneo:batch:job-queue-consumer-daemon
fi;
```

Then in the crontab file you run the bash file.

Answer (score 1):

There are special services for such tasks. For example http://supervisord.org/

> Supervisor is a client/server system that allows its users to monitor and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems.

And you can manage it via f.e https://github.com/supervisorphp/supervisor

Comment: +1 because this is the recommended Akeneo tool to control your batch processes: https://docs.akeneo.com/2.2/install_pim/manual/daemon_queue.html#supervisor

Answer (score 0):

A command working on command line and not working in CRON, this happened to me and here is what solved my problem.

Run `echo $PATH` in your terminal, copy entire output.

Then type `crontab -e` and at top of file, write this

```
PATH=WHATEVER_YOU_COPIED_FROM_LAST_COMMAND_OUTPUT
```

**PS:** (more suggestions)

I think you need to install `apt-get install postfix` on Ubuntu to be able to send emails.

You should also see CRON logs by

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), it handles these kinds of issues with automatic restart on failed services, additionaly, you can try to set the akeneo commands as a service.

Otherwise, if you would like to do it using cronjobs, you may have an issue with the php binary, you need to setup the absolute path :

```
e.g : /usr/bin/php
```

I would also recommend if you use cronjob:

1. Check the logs of the cronjob for additional issues

   grep CRON /var/log/syslog
2. Clean it up using a standalone bash script (don't forget to chmod +x)